# Internet connection logs

Tags: 22.04, internet, log

Is there a way to monitor internet connections and get a log file that states what time of the day is the internet disconnected when when it was back ?
I am using Ubuntu 22.04

**Edit :** the laptop is always connected to wifi and it is always on. and it is supposed to remain connected the internet. I want a log file that shows when it was down and when it was connected again.

Comment: Is this a desktop or a server version of Ubuntu 22.04? Is it connected by Ethernet cable, or WiFi? Is the computer always on? Is is always supposed to remain connected to the internet? [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1499842/edit) and add all these information.

Comment: Is this for permanent monitoring? If you want to just monitor a connection for a few days or something, then a very simple method is to use `ping` and log the output of that to a file you can look at to see where breaks occur.

Comment: See [How to test an Internet connection with bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929368/how-to-test-an-internet-connection-with-bash) in Stack Overflow.

Comment: You could adapt this: I've written a bash script to help with this: `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic` It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect or do something else.

Comment: @TommyPeanuts it is for permanent monitoring

Comment: @user68186 I have edited the questions

Answer (score 1):

Although this is [mostly answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929368/how-to-test-an-internet-connection-with-bash), you are also asking for a log file that states what time of the day the internet disconnected and when it was back.

This script (`monitor.sh`, based on the linked answer by [user3439968](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439968/user3439968)) will check if the machine is online. It then does not report anything unless the machine goes offline:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Your preferred date stamp format:
d=`date --rfc-3339=seconds`

# Use a file to record the start of any down time:
f=/tmp/offline

# Test connectivity.
# NOTE: You can use any connectivity test below that exits with 0 if successful. 
# The rest of the script will work as described.

echo -e "GET http://google.com HTTP/1.0\n\n" | nc google.com 80 > /dev/null 2>&1

# Check to see if we're back online after an outage, 
# otherwise report as still offline:

if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then

  if [ -f $f ] ; then
      echo "Back Online $d"
      rm -f $f
  fi

else

  echo "Offline $d"
  touch $f
fi
```

A time stamped log file can then be created during an offline episode, confirming the time of each test during the episode, and when the machine came back on line.

Call it every 10 seconds on a cron job like this:

`*/10 * * * * * /path/to/monitor.sh &>> /path/to/monitor.log`